# "Index by" equivalent in Postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

While migrating from oracle I had a problem with indexed array-types in packages

In Oracle a typical way to store user-defined types' tables is

TYPE X IS TABLE OF Y INDEX BY (for example BINARY_INTEGER or VARCHAR2);

In PostgreSQL an equivalent statement might be something like:

CREATE DOMAIN X AS Y[];

but is there any way to add the indexing type in this statement?

Comment: you don't need to create a specific type to be able to use an array. Just declare an array variable in your procedure

Comment: the question is about types in packages, which are used everywhere, so they should by somehow "globally" declared with the right indexing.

Comment: Every data type already has an array type as well. No need to define anything

Comment: Well, Postgres has no packages. And thus no "types declared in packages". But again: you don't need to declare a separate type to be able to use an array. All you need to do, is to declare a variable of type `y[]` wherever you want to use such a "table of ... index ..." thing

Comment: What is the actual problem you try to solve? What should the code do?

Comment: The main problem is that the DB in oracle is huge, and names of X and Y are usually so different from each other, so I can't use the array which is automatically created by postgres since it's hard to change all calls of such type in all functions and procedures. So I was looking for a proper approach, creating a domain (in a postgres schema instead of the oracle package) partially solves the problem. The other part about the right indexing of such type is still unresolved..

Comment: To me as a non-Oracle user, it’s still not clear what you try to achieve.